# Unit Tests Нужна помощь

Tags: php, yii2, phpunit, codeception, mock

Всем привет! Пишу на PHP, в качестве фреймворка использую Yii2, для написания тестов использую Codeception. Сразу скажу, что в написании тестов я новичок. Пока пишу простые тесты. Но вот дошел до места, где нужно внедрять мок-объекты. Почитал что это такое и с чем его едят. Пробовал, работает. Проблема в том, что я переделал метод, который тестирую для того, чтобы их использовать (просто для проверки, затем откатил).

Вопрос в том, **как обходиться когда у меня в тестируемом методе вызывается компонент в методе глобально**, через *Yii::$app->компонент->метод()* ? То есть я не могу передать в тестируемый метод явно созданный мок-объект, чтобы дернуть его замоканный метод.

Помогите разобраться как правильно замокать в таких случаях. Наверняка есть грамотное решение для таких случаев. Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 0):

В общем выхода я нашел два. Либо добавить тестовый конфиг, в котором будет полностью замокан используемый компонент, либо что более правильнее, это вынести глобальный вызов методов компонентов в отдельные методы и мокать непосредственно эти методы.